# The curve $x^3− y^3= 1$ is asymptotic to the line $x = y$. Find the point on the curve farthest from the line $x = y$

Tags: real-analysis

**(NBHM_2006_PhD Screening Test_Analysis)**

> The curve $x^3− y^3= 1$ is asymptotic to the line $x = y$. Find the
>   point on the curve farthest from the line $x = y$

how should i solve this problem

Comment: how should i respond to a question with no attempted solution?

Comment: @anorton This is a new user who doesn't know the site conventions. There's no need for snark.

Comment: @Potato True... (Sorry ketu.)  I'm more tired than I should be when I'm posting comments correcting people.  :-\  For reference, ketu: We like to see attempts at solutions here on Math.SE.  This helps us address the root difficulties you are having with a given problem.  Have you tried anything that didn't work, or are you completely stuck on where to start?

Comment: actually i dint know how to start.give some hints please?

Comment: @ketu In what context did you encounter this problem? (Also, at Math.SE we encourage the use of your shift key and punctuation.)

Comment: @anorton No worries!

Answer (score 7):

Hint: can you see why the slope of the curve at that point would be the sane as the slope of the line?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Step 1) Consider lines of the form $y = x+ C$.

$\frac {C}{\sqrt{2}}$ represents the distance between any point on the line, and the line $y=x$. We are looking for the largest absolute value of C such that a point of $x^3 - y^3 = 1 $ lies on the line. This is equivalent to solving for $\frac {dy}{dx} = A$ (some value for you to determine).

Step 2) Proceed by implicit differentiation, to get that the point satisfying $\frac {dy}{dx}=A$ also satisfies $y^2 = x^2$. Hence, solve for the point.

Comment: I would request you not to feel bad for me editing your answer.. I understand till the statement that "We are looking for the largest absolute value of $C$ such that a point of $x^3-y^3=1$ lies on the line $y=x$"..(I really like this idea :) :) :)) I could not follow why would be that be equivalent to $\frac{dy}{dx}=A$.. are we not trying to maximize $C$ such that $x^3-y^3=1$ and $y=x+C$.. I mean, $x^3-y^3=1$ with $y=x+C$ would imply $x^3-(x+C)^3=1$ i.e., $3Cx^2+3c^2x+(C^3+1)=0$.. I am confused.. could you please clarify this one.. Thank You.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No worries. Think of the family of curves of the form $y=x+C$. Intuitively, we want the largest value of $C$, such that this line still intersects the curve. If the curve intersects the line twice, then we can certainly push the line out further. Hence, there is only 1 intersection, thus tangential, and so we want to find a point on the curve which satisfies $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 $.

Comment: I am still confused... I  see that for $x^3-y^3=1$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2}{3y^2}=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$.. we want this slope to be same as that of $y=x+C$ i.e., $\frac{x^2}{y^2}=1$ but then? :(

Comment: Remember that you want the point to lie on the curve, so you still have $x^3-y^3=1$ as a condition. Use the above to solve the cubic and find the real roots.