# The curve $x^3-y^3=1$ is asymptotic t the line $x=y$. Find the point n the curve farthest from the line $x=y$.

Tags: analysis, asymptotics

```
The curve $x^3-y^3=1$ is asymptotic t the line $x=y$.  

Find the point in the curve farthest from the line $x=y$
```

This is just need of further details in [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268927/the-curve-x3%E2%88%92-y3-1-is-asymptotic-to-the-line-x-y-find-the-point-on-the)

Kindly give details about, if we are talking about asymtotic curve to the line $x=y$, what does it really means. And why we need the family of curves $y=x+C$ to look this problem(as in the answer given by Calvin).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}&
{\rm f}\left(\,x\,\right)\equiv x - \left(\,x^{3} - 1\,\right)^{1/3}\quad \mbox{always decreases becauses}\quad
{\rm f'}\left(\,x\,\right)<0\quad\mbox{when}\quad x > 1.
\\[5mm]&
\left(\,1,0\,\right)\quad\mbox{is the farthest point from the line}\quad y = x.
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: give details.. i couldnt understand

Comment: @gloom Done. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid $(1,0)$ is not the farthest point. Detailed answers, recent, at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102083/find-the-point-on-the-curve-farthest-from-the-line-x-y-0

Comment: @WillJagy I assumed the OP was thinking about the case $x > 0$. I can modify my answer to avoid this restriction. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, I put a good picture of it at yesterday's http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102083/find-the-point-on-the-curve-farthest-from-the-line-x-y-0/1102115#1102115  I do not think either this OP or yesterday's have much idea what the question is about.

Comment: @WillJagy I believe your answer at your provided link is pretty fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The distance from a point $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfying $x^3 - y^3 = 1$ to the line $y = x$ must be measured along a line segment perpendicular to $y = x$; that is to say, the foot of the perpendicular $(x_1, y_1)$ must satisfy the system $$x_1 = y_1, \quad y_1 - y_0 = -(x_1 - x_0),$$ or quite simply $$x_1 = y_1 = \frac{x_0 + y_0}{2}.$$  Therefore, the distance is given by $$D(x_0,y_0) = \frac{|x_0 - y_0|}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{|(y_0^3+1)^{1/3} - y_0|}{\sqrt{2}}.$$  Taking the derivative of the numerator with respect to $y_0$ and locating the critical points gives $y_0 = -2^{-1/3}$, hence by symmetry $(x_0, y_0) = (\pm 2^{-1/3}, \mp 2^{-1/3})$ are the desired solutions, with maximal distance $2^{1/6}$.

Answer (score 0):

$(x-y)\left(\frac34(x+y)^2+\frac14(x-y)^2\right)=1$
so $x-y$ is greatest when $(x+y)^2$ is smallest.